# TypeError at /en/ string indices must be integers

Tags: django, saleor

I am getting started with Saleor and followed the installation for Windows. After running the server I am getting an error during template rendering that involves the menu.html and the shop.py files.

```
@register.inclusion_tag("footer_menu.html")
def footer_menu(site_menu=None):
    menu_items = site_menu.json_content if site_menu else []
    return {"menu_items": menu_items}

@register.simple_tag
def get_menu_item_name(menu_item, lang_code):
    translated = menu_item["translations"].get(lang_code)
    if translated:
        return translated["name"]
    return menu_item["name"]
```

TypeError at /en/
string indices must be integers

11 {% get_menu_item_name lang_code=LANGUAGE_CODE menu_item=item %}

32 translated = menu_item['translations'].get(lang_code)

File "C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\my_project\saleor\saleor\core\templatetags\shop.py", line 32, in get_menu_item_name
    translated = menu_item["translations"].get(lang_code)
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: `menu_item` appears to be a string and not a dictionary

Comment: @DKRipper Consider reposting your comment as an answer, since it *is* an answer.

Answer (score 0):

menu_items in function above. removed the s and it worked.